# Load a grafana dashboard using http api

Tags: grafana, graphite, graphite-carbon

I am trying to automate some parts of the monitoring infrastructure, and as part of that it would be really handy to load the dashboards I want using the grafana http api. I can list folders, and load dashboard metadata, but I am not able to load the dashboard itself. By loading the dashboard I mean that grafana queries the backend.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question but I will try to answer.

The API is "only" for managing Grafana and not for viewing. That's why you can do the things you said but as you see in the docs, there is no way to interact with the dashboard itself. (maybe excluding creating or updating one with JSON)
http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/

What I imagine you want is to integrate a Panel in some other place. That's why there is the option to "Share" a Panel in the Dashboard itself. This will create a URL or an iframe to embed in a web page. To get there, click the Title of a Panel and select "Share".